# How can I add Arraylist in the alert dialog?

Tags: android

I created a Arraylist containing all contacts of my mobile and I want to put this Arraylist inside the alert dialog.How can i do this?please reply me

Comment: come with proper error and show some of your work. if you need any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
     builder.setTitle("Contacts");
     builder.setMessage(your_arraylist.toString());
     builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
     builder.show();
```

Comment: Thank you.I convert my Arraylist into the String array and set it to the alert dialog and it work properly thank you so much for your help. :)

Comment: glad I could be of help. Just mark this as the correct ans so that the community can benefit.